# Simple PHP MySQL check if row exists returning null result

Tags: php, mysql

I'm trying to build a simple postcode/ zip code check for our restaurant to check if a customer is within a list of postcodes we serve. Every time I query the postcode it returns a "not found" result and I can't work out why.

```
 $result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM functions-postcodes WHERE postcode = 'PO111XX'");
if(mysql_num_rows($result) == 0) {
     echo "Postcode not within coverage area (postcode not found in table)";
} else {
     echo "Postcode IS within coverage area";
}
```

Here is what the database table looks like:
[Database screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/X2oLp.png)

Comment: Have you check these same query execute in phpmyadmin is it gives error?

Comment: is it 0 or O ? It looks like You have a big letter O stored in database.

Comment: If you're writing new code, **_please_ don't use the `mysql_*` functions**. They are old and broken, were deprecated in PHP 5.5 (which is so old it no longer even receives security updates), and completely removed in PHP 7. Use [`PDO`](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php) or [`mysqli_*`](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php) with _prepared statements_ and _parameter binding_ instead. See http://stackoverflow.com/q/12859942/354577 for details.

Answer (score 1):

Your table name should not have a `-` in it. Consider renaming the table to `functions_postcode` or something like that. If that is not possible, use backticks to escape special characters in (table) names:

```
SELECT * FROM `functions-postcodes` ...
```

That, and:

1. Check for errors when you do not get the desired result (in logs or with error function calls)
2. Stop using `mysql_*`. They are [deprecated](http://php.net/manual/en/migration55.deprecated.php). Use MySQLi or PDO instead. Use prepared statements too.